# Why won't this transition work?

Tags: css, css-transitions

I'm trying to make the `div` fade in, to no avail. 
I am not sure why its not working.

How can I achieve this effect using only CSS?

### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/54bxS/)

CSS:

```
 .works a {
  display: table !important;
  width: 100%;
  background: url("http://www.9ori.com/store/media/images/8ab579a656.jpg") center no-repeat;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 300px; 
 }

  .works a div {
    display: none;
    opacity: 0; 
 }

  .works a:hover div {
    transition: opacity 1s;
    color: white;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
    display: table-cell;
    opacity: 1;
    vertical-align: middle; 
 }
```

HTML:

```
<div class="works">
    <a href="blah.ca">
        <div class="work-hover">
            This was my first ever professionally designed website. Also note that this was before I discovered SASS, so the coding isn't as streamlined as possible. But the end result is great looking, and fully functional in most modern browsers.
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
```

Comment: I found one way is to remove the `display: table-cell` from the hover and replace the `display: none` with it. Unfortunately, even if I have a transition on both hover and non-hover only one way works.

Comment: Got it http://jsfiddle.net/54bxS/1/

Comment: Add transition to the default state. Not to the hover state. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_CSS_transitions

Comment: You need to do it for both if you want the effect to happen on hover and off hover

Comment: Where did you read that?!? http://jsfiddle.net/54bxS/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem was setting the display. Trick is to set all initial styles to the unseen element, then only trigger and change the transiting style.

Solution:

http://jsfiddle.net/54bxS/1/

CSS:

```
.works a {
  display: table !important;
  width: 100%;
  background: url("http://www.9ori.com/store/media/images/8ab579a656.jpg") center no-repeat;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 300px; }
  .works a div {
    display: table-cell;
    transition: opacity 1s;
    color: white;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
    vertical-align: middle;
    opacity: 0; }
  .works a:hover div {
    transition: opacity 1s;
    opacity: 1; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Translate in CSS3 animation. You can get a lively fade in animation by using that.